# Is the median blocksize measured over the last 100 or 720 blocks?

Tags: median-blocksize

I have seen both 100 and 720 being referenced as the proper number for determining median block-size for the purpose of calculating miner penalties. Which one is correct?

Is Monero changed its code from 100 to 720 (or the other way around) at some point what was the reason for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is 100 blocks (CRYPYONOTE_REWARD_BLOCKS_WINDOW in src/cryptonote_config.h). I think I've confused this with the difficulty window before, which is 720. I don't remember it changing.